# Problema a la hora de leer y grabar datos de audio en C

Tags: c, audio

Tengo un programa en el que, mediante Electron, grabo o reproduzco audio, lo envío al Node.JS que hay detrás y de ahí, lo envío por nanomsg a un proceso C/C++.

Desde Node no tengo ningún problema para grabar a fichero, el problema es en C/C++. Los datos que recibo, si yo tengo un tamaño de chunk de 1024, en C/C++ es de 4096 bytes cada chunk que recibo.

Yo estoy cogiendo del siguiente modo los datos que me llegan por nanomsg:
Tengo definido un puntero a memoria:

```
    char *buf = (char*) malloc(1024*4);;
```

Y recojo los datos del siguiente modo:

```
    result = nn_recv(sock, &buf,NN_MSG ,0);
```

Para almacenarlo uso strcat, cosa que no estoy del todo seguro que sea lo mejor, pero mis conocimientos en C son mínimos, siendo audio un puntero para concatenar todos los datos:

```
    strcat(audio,buf);
```

Mientras se envían todos los datos, los recojo y los concateno, entonces después procedo a guardarlos en un fichero, por ahora sin cabecera, ya que con poder reproducirlo como raw en Audacity me vale por el momento.

De este modo grabo en fichero:

```
FILE * ff = fopen("ruta/fichero.wav","wb");
for(int j = 0; j < strlen(audio); j++){
    fwrite(&audio[j],1,1 ,ff);
}
fclose(ff);
```

Pero a la hora de reproducirlo en Audacity, es todo ruido.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dijo *Jack el destripador*, Vamos por partes:

Si miramos la documentación de [`nm_rec( )`](https://nanomsg.org/v1.1.5/nn_recv.html)

> `nanomsg` can allocate the buffer for you. To do so, let the `buf` parameter be a pointer to a void* variable (pointer to pointer) to the receive buffer and set the len parameter to NN_MSG

Por lo tanto, tu llamada

```
char *buf = (char*) malloc(1024*4);
```

es totalmente innecesaria. Te basta simplemente con declarar la variable:

```
char *buf;
```

> Para almacenarlo uso strcat, cosa que no estoy del todo seguro que sea lo mejor

Estás **totalmente en lo correcto**: **no debes** usar `strcat( )`. Sin entrar en detalles, `strcat( )` está pensada para trabajar con **cadenas**: depende de encontrar un *byte* `0`. Con lo que su comportamiento trabajando con *bytes* arbitrarios es poco menos que aleatorio: te generará resultados **totalmente inesperados**.

> De este modo grabo en fichero:
>           for(int j = 0; j < strlen(audio); j++){

Otro error. `strlen( )` es similar a `strcat( )`: está pensada para trabajar con cadenas, y también depende de encontrar un *byte* `0`. Igualmente, obtendrás resultados totalmente aleatorios.

El resultado final de todo esto es:

```
size_t audio_size = 0U;
char *buf;
int result = nn_recv( sock, &buf, NN_MSG, 0 );

...

memcpy( audio, buf, (size_t)result );
audio_size += (size_t)result;
free( buf );

...

FILE *ff = fopen( "ruta/fichero.wav", "wb" );
fwrite( audio, audio_size,1 ,ff );
fclose( ff );
free( audio );
```

Nota que es necesario redimensionar *sobre la marcha* el buffer `audio` (llamando, por ejemplo, a `realloc( )`, e ir liberando los bloques de memoria cuando dejamos de necesitarlos (llamando a `free( )`).

Comment: Solucionado, el estar trabajando con esas funciones para cadenas me estaba destrozando todos los datos. Una respuesta genial, muchisimas gracias.